# Comprehension - gave them the run of the base grounds still in Ukrainian hands

Tags: meaning, grammar

> During the ordeal, the colonel gave reporters and TV crews **the run of the base grounds still in Ukrainian hands**, and held impromptu news conferences in front of brigade headquarters.

First of all, what does **the run of the base grounds** mean? Break it down for me as far as each word in the phrase goes, please. Secondly, do I understand that line correctly if I change it a little bit by adding some words that help me tie things together to make the connection more obvious: **the run of the base grounds THAT WERE still in Ukrainian hands**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> During the ordeal, the colonel gave reporters and TV crews the run of the base grounds still in Ukrainian hands, and held impromptu news conferences in front of brigade headquarters.

*The colonel gave reporters and TV crews the run of (**= free access to**) the base grounds (**that were**) still in Ukrainian hands*...